# Rudin's RCA: Redundant argument to show regularity?

Tags: real-analysis, riesz-representation-theorem

[image]

Although I understand the proof of the theorem, but I wonder about why proof of $(a)$ needs such a complex progress. The key idea is that if we can show $\mu(V - E) < \epsilon$ for any $E$, then by a complement argument we can prove $(a)$. But showing $\mu(V-E) < \epsilon $ is just a outer regularity of $\mu$, which is proved in the Riesz representation theorem, a theorem 2.14 in the same book.

Is there something I misunderstood?

Thanks!

Comment: "Complement argument' works if you have finite measure.  Here we are interested in infinite measures also (like Lebesgue measure) for which outer regularity does not immediately give inner regularity.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Can you explain a bit more? I really don't understand where we need to use finite measure. In fact, $V - F = (V - E) \cup (E - F)$ where $E \subseteq V$, $E^c \subseteq W$ and $V-E $ and $E-F$ are disjoint measurable sets, so we just add them.

Comment: Write down your simpler proof and we will try to show why it doesn't work.